Property of Lipschitz function [reference]
I am looking for a reference to quote where this fact is proved.
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz and let $\Delta \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Borel set with strictly positive Lebesgue measure.
If $f|_{\Delta}=0$, then $\nabla f=0$ a.e. on $\Delta$.
(Obviously the gradient $\nabla f$ exists almost everywhere in view of Rademacher's theorem).

Theorem 3.3 (differentiability on level sets), proposition (i) from "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" by Evans and Gariepy should give you this when combined with the fact that a globally Lipschitz function is locally Lipschitz.

@Dmarks Many thanks!
